# Jmeter Mail Reader Sampler "file" protocol-How to read message files(.msg) from a folder

Tags: email, csv, jmeter

I have outlook message files(.msg) in a folder. I want mail reader sampler to read these messages from a folder..

I could copy file path and use csv to read these messages but the message id is dynamic so the file name changes, therefore I have to copy the file path every time to let mail sampler read these messages... Is there any alternative to read these messages dynamically.

My Test Plan

Mail Reader Sampler:
protocol: file
Server: C:\temp\apache Jmeter\

apache Jmeter folder contain my .msg files

when I run my test I get the response 0 message found.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to populate .msg files list first (which can be dynamic) and send them to the server.

1. Get list of files to send and store them into JMeter Variables
2. Pass JMeter Variables holding file paths to SMTP Sampler

In regards to point 1, I would suggest to obtain file list via scripting.

Assuming following Test Plan Structure:

- Add a Thread Group (all defaults)
- Add d a Beanshell Sampler as a child of Thread Group
- In the "Script" area add following code:

  ```
  File folder = new File("c:/temp/JMeter");
  File [] files2send = folder.listFiles();

  int counter = 1;

  for (File file : files2send) {
      if (file.getName().endsWith(".msg")){           

      vars.put("FILE_" + counter, file.getPath());
      counter++;
      }
  }
  ```

This will save files, you will be sending as JMeter Variables like:

```
FILE_1=c:\temp\JMeter\something.msg
FILE_2=c:\temp\JMeter\somethingmore.msg
FILE_3=c:\temp\JMeter\somethingelse.msg
```

You may wish to check [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed explanation of Beanshell test elements and a kind of cookbook.

After that you can use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate through files and add them to your request

Add For Each Controller as a child of Thread Group (same level as the Beanshell Sampler

Make sure that For Each Controller has following configuration:

1. Input variable prefix: `FILE`
2. Output variable name: `CURRENTFILE`
3. Add _ before number is **checked**

Add SMTP Sampler **as a child** of For Each Controller

Access file you want to send as `${CURRENTFILE}` in "Attach Files" stanza of the HTTP Request

Comment: I appreciate for the response, but I want to read msg files(which are dynamic) from a folder. I am using Mail reader sampler to get this job done. I do not want to send messages. Sorry if my question confused you.